# Select a specific part of a value from a column in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i´m new in SQL and want to solve following case.

I have a table in a MariaDB named inventories. In this table are 2 columns: identifier and data.
I want to select and output a specific part in the column data, if the identifier is a specific one.

For example:

| identifier | data |
| --- | --- |
| steam:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | ...some data...,"Serial":"ZF3CJ8L1rrKjwP7nKTzb",...some more data... |

The only part, that i want in the output is this: "Serial":"ZF3CJ8L1rrKjwP7nKTzb" but the part behind "Serial":" is a random value.

How can i solve this?

(i put a screenshot in here, table does not work for me in editor[screenshot of table in stackoverflow editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtMwS.png).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING(data, LOCATE('"Serial":"', DATA) + 0, 31)) FROM inventories where identifier = 'steam:xxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SubString function, which only returns a certain amount of character and starts a whatever character you want.

Comment: Yeah, i see the posibillity but the part is not always on the same part in the data value.